# cannot run sudo apt-get update

Tags: apt

I am unable to run the sudo apt-get update command as well as install any packages.  Here is the return from sudo apt-get update:

```
   sabo@Ace:/etc/apt$ sudo apt-get update
Err h ttp://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg
  Could not connect to Ace:80 (127.0.1.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err h ttp://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
  Could not connect to Ace:80 (127.0.1.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err h ttp://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to Ace:80:
Err h ttp://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to Ace:80:
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch h ttp://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubu ntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg                                                                                                      Could not connect to Ace:80 (127.0.1.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/Rel                                                                                                    ease.gpg  Unable to connect to Ace:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/R                                                                                                    elease.gpg  Unable to connect to Ace:80:

W: Failed to fetch h ttp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/Rele                                                                                                    ase.gpg  Could not connect to Ace:80 (127.0.1.1). - connect (111: Connection ref                                                                                                    used)

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used                                                                                                     instead.
```

Any help at all is greatly appreciated, I've been unable to figure out the problem for some time.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using a HTTP proxy. You can disable it -- see how [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto#Setting_up_apt-get_to_use_a_http-proxy).

It might be worth the time to find out why you are using a proxy.